# Самый частый символ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать чтобы я вводил слово и мне писало символ который появляется
в слове наиболее часто. Не лезет в голову как можно сделать это. Пожалуйста помогите. Например у нас есть слово: приоритет. Нам должно вывести, что наиболее частый символ это и, т . Не нужно чтобы оно писало количество, а только выводило символ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

word = 'приоритет'
c = Counter(word)
print(c.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Т.к. метод `most_common` возвращает список самых частых значений (даже если мы запросили одно самое частое значение), то нужно взять первый элемент (для этого нужен первый `[0]`). Каждый элемент в этом списке - пара `(элемент, количество)`, поэтому нужно взять первый элемент еще раз.

Вообще, в слове "приоритет" есть 3 буквы, которые встречаются по два раза (р, и, т), выведет только одну из них (у меня вывело "р").

Вариант решения без использования `Counter`:

```
word = 'приоритет'

# Подсчитываем количество вхождений каждой буквы в слове
c = dict()

for letter in word:
    c[letter] = c.get(letter, 0) + 1
    # .get(letter, 0) вернет значение по ключу letter или 0, если такого ключа нет

print(c)  # {'п': 1, 'р': 2, 'и': 2, 'о': 1, 'т': 2, 'е': 1}

# Выводим ключ, которому соответствует наибольшее из значений
# (точнее, один из таких ключей)
print(max(c.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])[0])  # р
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение без использования модуля `Counter`:

```
text = "приритет"
#выбираем буквы
letters = set(text)
#считаем буквы
count = []
for letter in letters:
    count.append((text.count(letter), letter))
count.sort(reverse=True)
print (count)
print(count[0][1])
```

вывести все буквы с одинаковым количеством вхождений, думаю, сам сможешь.
а этот код выведет:

```
[(2, 'т'), (2, 'р'), (2, 'и'), (1, 'п'), (1, 'е')]
т
```

Благодаря наставлению старших товарищей (см. примечание  @gil9red), напишу более понятный для наметаного глаза вариант кода без `Count`:

```
text = "приритет"
#считаем буквы
count = sorted([(text.count(letter), letter) for letter in set(text)], reverse=True)
print (count)
print(count[0][1])
```

Правда, изящно и почти по английски? просто читаешь..
"счетчик равен отсортированному по убыванию списку составленному для каждой буквы из набора букв исходного текста. Причем каждый элемент этого списка состоит из пары: (количество буквы в тексте, буква)
Такой себе однострочный функциональный вариант...

Comment: `count = [(text.count(letter), letter) for letter in letters]`?

Comment: `О(n**2)`. Конечно для подсчета в слове не критично, но все равно боль.

Comment: @gil9red - ну да, 
тогда уж еще минус одна строка:
`count = sorted([(text.count(letter), letter) for letter in letters], reverse=True)`
но парень похоже новичек, я и написал попонятнее.
Хотя да, перепишу по-взрослому ниже.
Спасибо.

Comment: @insolor а вот по алгоритму со словарем - респект.  Он-да, О(n) и потому быстрее.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, во-первых, у О большого не бывает "точного значения", это ассимптотика. Во-вторых, в `Counter` и вариант с `dict` это технически один и тот же вариант. Если ваш вариант быстрее чем `Counter` на небольших строках, то он точно так же будет быстрее чем `dict`. В-третьих, можно `sorted` заменить на `max`, будет еще быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием только цикла, условного оператора и метода строк count.
Если два различных символа встречается одинаковое число раз, выведет последний из таких символов

```
s = input()
max_count = 0
max_char = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.count(s[i]) >= max_count:
        max_count = s.count(s[i])
        max_char = s[i]
print(max_char)
```

Comment: count - это фактически линейный поиск элемента по массиву (цикл), сложность алгоритма получается квадратичной.